# Javascript: angularjs: multiple conditions for specified number and text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Sorry for that dumb question and my poor English. i am beginner in programming, if i press counter button increases number with 1 if i reach on 34 number value then how can i use condition to change text display and rest value to 0, when again i reach to 34 number value text change with next text value, how can i do this? i have no idea but what i wrote here is it guide me for my mistakes, `

```
$scope.newfunc = function () {
  $('#display').text(Number($('#display').text())*0); // reset to 0
  $('.zikar').text('s_text'); // show text in display

  $(document).on('click','#count', function(){
    $('#display').text(Number($('#display').text())+1); // increases number with 1
    console.log($('#display').text());

    if($('.zikar').text('s_text') && $('#display').text()==34){
      alert('34');
      $('#display').text(Number($('#display').text())*0);
      $('.zikar').text('A_text');
    }

    if($('.zikar').text('A_text') && $('#display').text()==34) {
      alert('34');
      $('#display').text(Number($('#display').text()) * 0);
      $('.zikar').text('A1_text');
    }

  });

// i dont know how but tried with loop but not working :( 

  for(var i=0; i<=$('#display').text().length; i++){

    if($('#display').text()==34){
  alert('34');
      $('#display').text(Number($('#display').text())*0);
      $('.zikar').text('A_text');
    }
  }
};`
```

and if i again and again trigger this function number increases with just 1 time not more then 1 how to condition this?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You are doing it not in an Angular way. Check this for beginning https://artandlogic.com/2013/03/angularjs-for-jquery-developers/

Comment: thanks for suggestion dear brother , i have coded that already in controller and angular app.. but i have not solved my jquery code problem, but thanks for help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you:

```
$scope.newfunc = function () {
    var _counter = 0;
    var dynamicText = 0;
    $("#counterBtn").on('click', function(){
        _counter++;
        if(_counter == 34){
            _counter = 0;
            dynamicText++
            $('.zikar').text("A"+dynamicText+"_text");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: dear i got idea i can add limit variable in my counter clicked button but it's not working with my changing different text value thrice times or more then 3x , can  u help me in this ?